# Solve the equation: $x²-5x-500=0$ Take the positive value of $ x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

> Solve the equation: $x²-5x-500=0$. Take the positive value of $ x$.

I am having a really bad time with this one.. Can someone give me the exact answer I posted above? I need the answer then the positive value of $x$.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you know how quadratic are solved?

Comment: For any equation of the form $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ , $x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

Answer (score 2):

You need two numbers that multiply together to $500$, yet differ by by only $5$.  Try different factors until you close in on the answer.

$10 * 50 = 500$, but they differ by $40$.  Try closer.

$20 * 25 = 500$, and they differ by $5$.

The middle term of the quadratic equation is negative, so the larger factor goes with the minus sign.

$x^2 - 5x - 500 = (x - 25)(x + 20)$

And you can easily determine the positive solution of $x$ from here.  The solutions to the equation are $25$ and $-20$, and your positive solution is $x = 25$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$x^2-5x-500=(x-25)(x+20)$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $x + 25$

This is how you solve it, by factoring

$(x+20)(x-25) = 0$.

Clearly $x = -20, 25$ thus, your positive answer is 25.

Answer (score 0):

Try apply Steven Product.

```
x²-x(a+b)+(a*b)
```

**Edited**:So knowing the expression `(x-x')(x-x'') = 0`
you need to find that each some of each block needs to be `0` to the product results `0`.
So you do: `x-x' = 0 -> x = x'` and `x-x'' = 0 -> x = x''`

That is the same of factoring using Sum and Product.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comparing $$x^2-5x-500 = x^2+(p+q)x+pq$$

we get

$$p+q = -5$$ and $$pq=-500$$

Solve the two equations to get $$p = -25, q = 20$$

Hence, $$x^2-5x-500=(x-25)(x+20)$$

Equating it to zero we get $$x=25,-20$$

Since you want positive solution the answer is $25$.

Answer (score 0):

$x²−5x−500=(x+20)(x−25)=0$ so $x=-20,25$ and the positive answer is $25$.